# Open source Machine learning Project with Scala

Tags: scala, machine-learning

I am pretty new to Scala and I think that the best way to learn a language is to learn from others. Is there any good scala open source project focusing on machine learning? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is probably a better question for [`scala-user`](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-user).

Comment: "Focus on ML" question too open ended, but: Spark and Twitter's large scale mapreduce libs, Factorie, breeze. For NLP: Stanford parser, scalaNLP, there's probably a dozen others

Answer (score 3):

You should checkout Breeze, it has quite a few built in ML algorithms, though the documentation can be sparse, I would recommend looking at the source:

http://www.scalanlp.org/

Answer (score 1):

That's not an OS project, but i just have to sugest you to watch the talk given by `Christopher Severs` and `Vitaly Gordon` on ScalaDays'13 on [Machine Learning With Scala](http://parleys.com/play/51c2e0f3e4b0ed877035684f/chapter0/about)